# PPTP VPN connection disconnecting when accesing an IP over VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, pptp

I have two PC lan behind a router. I am connecting to my company network through a VPN. I was not able to reach an IP, nor access the internet. The VPN connection would be disconnected automatically.

**My LAN information:**

gateway 192.168.5.1
my pc 192.168.5.2

**VPN**

client 192.168.2.7
subnet mask 255.255.255.255
no gateway defined
server 192.168.2.1

So in the VPN setup I removed the checkbox "Use default gateway on remote network". Now I am able to access internet, the VPN connection stays alive. To access the remote server I routed the IP through VPN gateway. I am able to ping the IP, but when I want to connect to a webserver on that IP through the browser my VPN connection gets disconnected as before.

What could be the reason? Is this some routing issue?